# Why is this RedirectMatch 301 replacing on ampersands?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a several RedirectMatch 301s in my .htaccess file. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(?i)/testurl/?$  https://www.myurl.com/search/doctors?category:affiliation=78|79|218|80&orderby_sort=doctors_last_name|asc&child:doctors_services=1967
```

When the redirect kicks in, it goes here:

```
https://www.myurl.com/search/doctors?category:affiliation=78|79|218|80/testurlorderby_sort=doctors_last_name|asc/testurlchild:doctors_services=1967
```

Note that the ampersands (&) in the query string are being replaced with the "testurl" from the RedirectMatch. Any ideas about what is going on here?

I'm running ExpressionEngine on Apache - not sure if this is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by escaping the "&" like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(?i)/testurl/?$  https://www.myurl.com/search/doctors?category:affiliation=78|79|218|80\&orderby_sort=doctors_last_name|asc\&child:doctors_services=1967
```